# subprocess.Popen communicate method open automaticaly the file, stops the program execution until I manually close the file

Tags: python, perl

I have one problem with the python subprocess module.

```
import os, subprocess

BLEU_SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'multi-bleu.perl')
command = BLEU_SCRIPT_PATH + ' %s < %s'
ref = "ref.en-fr.test.txt"
hyp = "hyp100.en-fr.test.txt"

p = subprocess.Popen(command % (ref, hyp), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result = p.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")
# ...
# ...
```

The multi-bleu.perl file does the evaluation and returns a real number or an error if any; but that's not my concern.
The last line of code automatically opens the multi-bleu.perl file with my default text editor, stops the program execution until I manually close the file.
How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `subprocess.Popen` interprets any shebang in the file. You need to specify the executable in the command to be executed. Also, Popen requires a list as first argument, so you need to "lift up" your string formatting into the command-list.

```
command = [
    '/path/to/perl',
    BLEU_SCRIPT_PATH + ' %s < %s' % (ref, hyp)
]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

You might also want to have a look at [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) which will make the code a bit easier.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was very helpful. I made my code on a linux platform (which apparently has a default perl interpreter) and when I came back to windows I didn't pay attention to this way of doing things.
Once the perl interpreter is installed and added to the environment variables we just have to do as in the following answer (what you proposed).

Comment: One way to think about it is that the Perl script itself is just an argument to the Perl interpreter. So the command you need to execute using subprocess is not the Perl *script*, but the interpreter itself.